# List index out of range using randint

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, random

I'm currently playing around with trying to append a random item (using randint) from a list to another list before adding the next item. Well, that's probably a weird way of putting it but I'm not sure how else to describe it - I apologize. So instead, here's my current code in question and the output I desire:

Code:

```
import random

lineIDPart3 = []
lineIDSpace6 = []
lineIDSpace6Poss = ["4", "0", "C", "8"]
lineIDSpace6Num = random.randint(0, 3)
while len(lineIDPart3) < 34:
    lineIDPart3.append(lineIDSpace6Poss[lineIDSpace6Num])
    if lineIDSpace6Num < 4:
        lineIDSpace6Num += 1
    else:
        lineIDSpace6Num = 0
print(lineIDPart3)
```

Example of the output I want:

```
["C", "8", "4", "0", "C", "8"...]
```

I'm pretty stumped on this one so any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Change lineIDSpace6Num < 4 to lineIDSpace6Num < 3.

Comment: What output do you get now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going one integer too far on this condition:

"`if lineIDSpace6Num < 4:`"
(with this condition you are allowing lineIDSpace6Num to increment by one if it's equal to 3)

Try changing the number from **4 to 3** (or better yet to `(len(lineIDSpace6Poss)-1)` in case you decide you want more characters in your generation list); because your array only has 4 elements that means your maximum value must me 3 otherwise you'll have an `index out of range` exception.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite straightforward. Because your `if statement` is `<4`, and then it +=1, so it means it will grow from 3 to 4 in loop. Just simply change

```
 if lineIDSpace6Num < 4:
```

to

```
 if lineIDSpace6Num < 3:
```

Your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
size=34
listy=["4", "0", "C", "8"]
random.shuffle(listy)
newlist=(listy*(int(size/len(listy))+len(listy)))[:size]
```

Is an easier way to do it

Comment: I donot think  it is right. Look at his code, he want the order to be preserved. Not  all random.

Comment: Oh I see. I'll fix it